# wheezy template dictionary variable lookup

Tags: python

I have the following wheezy template:

```
@for i in pos:
      @i[0] : @swi['x'] : @i[1]
@end
```

which for instance would output:

```
Z:val:x
```

yet, I would like to do something like:

```
@swi[@i[1]!s]
```

but it returns syntax error.
I need to lookup in swi using the current iteration data.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "toto.py", line 53, in <module>
        template = engine.get_template('x')
      File "/Soft/fox_dev/redhat/dist/other/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wheezy.template-0.1.151-py2.6.egg/wheezy/template/engine.py", line 41, in get_template
        self.compile_template(name)
      File "/Soft/fox_dev/redhat/dist/other/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wheezy.template-0.1.151-py2.6.egg/wheezy/template/engine.py", line 89, in compile_template
        source, name)['render']
      File "/Soft/fox_dev/redhat/dist/other/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wheezy.template-0.1.151-py2.6.egg/wheezy/template/compiler.py", line 26, in compile_source
        source = adjust_source_lineno(source, name, self.source_lineno)
      File "/Soft/fox_dev/redhat/dist/other/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wheezy.template-0.1.151-py2.6.egg/wheezy/template/comp.py", line 21, in adjust_source_lineno
        source = compile(source, name, 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
      File "x", line 7
        w('          '); w(i[0]); w(' : '); w(swi[@i[1]]); w(' : '); w(i[1]); w('\n')
                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i've tried:

```
@swi[@i[1]!s]
@swi['@i[1]!s']
@swi[@i[1]]
@swi['@i[1]']
```

Comment: done. error added at the end

Comment: I assume you've tried `@swi[i[1]]` ?

Comment: just before you wrote it !!! thanks.

Comment: write it down as I did in an answer. And i'll accept it.

Comment: why is the @ not allowed here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is:

```
@swi[i[1]]
```

I'm not sure why the @ is not allowed here...